# Running a meteor app on Nodejitsu

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, nodejitsu

Deployed a meteor app to a Nodejitsu trial environment but failed to get it to run. Upon executing `jitsu deploy` from my meteor app directory I get the following error: `ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined`.

If you have gotten a meteor app up and running on Nodejitsu, please highlight the steps you took and dependencies I might be missing. I will use your suggestions and try to get my app to run. Thanks.

```
// package.json contents
{
  "name": "test123-meteor",
  "subdomain": "user123.test123-meteor",

/*
* Really not sure about this line here...
*/
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node client/controllers/GeneralController.js"
  },
  "version": "0.0.1-2",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: `meteor bundle` then deploy the app with nodejitsu?

Comment: From what I've heard, node-fibers (which Meteor uses) isn't currently compatible with nodejitsu, although older versions apparently worked.

Comment: it's not going to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504324/where-can-we-host-meteor-meteorite-applications

Comment: @booyaa Any specific reason why? The link didn't contain any reason why meteor would not run on Nodejitsu.. Unless I missed sth.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this today and didn't have a problem when using demeteorizer.  I wrote the following small article about it on Meteorpedia which includes my custom build script which greatly simplifies deployment.

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Nodejitsu

Answer (score 1):

Meteor won't run on nodejitsu until this bug is fixed: [node-fibers won't build on SmartOS](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/94). If you want it, you should star the bug or even look into fixing it. (Naively, it looks like the kind of thing that needs more persistence than brilliance; a build issue on just that one OS for a package which builds unmodified on over 5 other OSs.)